# Munin graph shows 3 Upgradable security packages (red alert) but apt does not install them

Tags: linux, apt, munin

I'm using this munin plugin : http://exchange.munin-monitoring.org/plugins/apt_ubuntu/details

The server is an ubuntu 10.04 up to date.

So..

This is my munin server, which on its own munin graph shows me a red alert on System, its an alert of  "3 Security Upgradable Packages".

But does packages are kept back.

What Should I do to make the alarm disapear?

```
root@fbmmu01:/home/admmarc# **apt-get update**
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net lucid Release.gpg
.......[some repos which show no error]
Reading package lists... Done
root@fbmmu01:/home/admmarc# **apt-get upgrade**
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
The following packages have been kept back:
  linux-generic linux-headers-generic linux-image-generic
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 3 not upgraded.
root@fbmmu01:/home/admmarc#
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, from the munin-exchange plugin page itself, on the comments I found this:

> Written by C. Alex Roeber on 'Oct. 25,
>   2010, 18:54.
>
> Remember that apt-update will not do
>   the kernel or a few other security
>   packages. run apt-get upgrade and it
>   will tell you which are not being
>   upgrade. Then run apt-get install on
>   them.
>
> goodluck

So I've done as it says:

> apt-get install linux-generic
>   linux-headers-generic
>   linux-image-generic

And after this:

```
root@fbmmu01:/home/admmarc# /etc/munin/plugins/apt-ubuntu 
security.value 0
updates.value 0
proposed.value 0
backports.value 0
other.value 0
total.value 0
```

So, its just becouse kernel packages don't care about upgrade, they need to be installed.

Comment: its untrue that "apt-get update" will not do the kernel.  The reality is that it won't install packages that aren't already installed and won't delete pacakges which are installed.  If upgrading a package requires changing the list of installed pacakges, you can use "apt-get dist-upgrade"